# Create an incremental backup without first a full backup

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup

I need to create an incremental backup (only files with more recent date changes). I used to be a fan of Cobian soft, but it seems to want to copy every file nowadays. I only need to copy about 300MB of changed data. I don't want to tax my back up HD and write all 800 GB over again.

#### EDIT

I used the Windows "copy and paste" command to backup a hard drive with movies and pictures about 6 months ago. Now I want to add onto my backup without rewriting those original files. I actually found a nice utility called bvckup that smartly only updates things that changed, but it MIRRORS the task. It deletes things from the destination directory that aren't in the source directory!

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: windows 7 x64 OS

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders

Comment: The best you can do is use something Beyond Compare, what you actually did, isn't even your typical backup.  You understand writting 800GB is nothing right?  Most of the files can be skipped if they already exist.

Comment: Well I'd rather write 1GB (upper limit) then rewrite 800GB every time I want to backup my files regularly and quickly. Won't leaving the computer on overnight to write 800GB wear out the HD significantly faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incremental backups are not only files with recent date changes. An incremental backup is a backup with changes **compared to** a previous baseline. E.g. compared to a full backup or a full backup and applied incrementals.

I am not sure what to call your desired backup, but incremental seems wrong.

As for archiving what you want: Most backup software respects the archive bit. Once that is set there is a note that the file is archived. That means that you should be able to use just about any backup software to archive recent/new files.

Comment: I used the windows "copy and paste" command to backup a hard drive with movies and pictures about 6 months ago. Now I want to add onto my backup without rewriting those original files. I actually found a nice utility called bvckup that smartly only updates things that changed, but it MIRRORS the task. It deletes things from the destination directory that aren't in the source directory!!!

Comment: I had some problems finding a windows version, but **rsync** is great for this. It compares the files in the source (folder or host) and target (folder or host) and only saves changes.  (A new file is 100% changed).